# Accessing Single Pandas Values with Different Locators

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'm building a script to compare single values between two pandas dataframes and I got stuck a while on the output value of a datetime. Can someone explain the difference between .iloc[0] and .item()?

I'm currently using .iloc[0] because I have single matches by the nature of the data, but in theory, .item() should yield the same output.

```py
    for _id in _ids:
        local_row = local_items[local_items["ID"]==_id]
        sp_row = sp_items[sp_items["ID"]==_id]
        for col in cols_to_check:
            local_row[col].iloc[0] # "2019-04-16 00:00:00"
            sp_row[col].iloc[0]    # "2019-04-12 00:00:00"
            local_row[col].item()  # "1555372800000000000"
            sp_row[col].item()     # "1555027200000000000"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Series.item()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.item.html)

Returns the first elements of the data as a `python scalar`.
The item() method returns the `Python timestamp`, that is the number of seconds elapsed from the date `Jan 01 1970 (UTC)`.

[`Series.iloc[0]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

Returns data at the specified position.
Where as the iloc[0] returns the datetime object which is presented in the format `"2019-04-16 00:00:00"`

[Example to convert between the two](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/timestamp-datetime)

Comment: Thanks, that’s what I assumed/doing but was looking for a concrete connection.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem myself recently. Item is giving you what you might consider to be like the "raw" timestamp data. You can fix it with `pd.to_datetime(variable_name)` where your variable name is equal to the string of numbers you get from using `.item()`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

item is pulling out the first value from the *underlying* data, in this case the underlying data is an int 1555372800000000000.

> return the first element of the underlying data as a python
>   scalar

This is read as a Timestamp using the constructor:

```
In [11]: pd.Timestamp(1555372800000000000)
Out[11]: Timestamp('2019-04-16 00:00:00')
```

which matches the date.

Note: This is the epoch time in nanoseconds:

```
In [12] pd.Timestamp(1555372800000000000, unit='ns')
Out[12]: Timestamp('2019-04-16 00:00:00')
```

---

Note: pandas item() calls directly numpy values, i.e. `s.values.item()`, so it looks like this is a numpy issue rather than a pandas one.